InFailedSQLTransaction error while doing "Insert into table ..."
I have a code to send data to postgresql using psycopg2 to connect.
connection = psycopg2.connect(<.connection details..>)
sql ="Insert into <tablename> (A, B, C) VALUES ('%s, '%s', '%s')"
val = ('D', 'E', 'F')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, val) #fails

saying - "InFailedSqlTransaction : current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of execution block"

You have ignored a previous error in this transaction. All commands after that will fail with this message until you rollback the transaction. Find the original error.


Use try/except as shown here psycopg2 exceptions. Then you can rollback on error. 2) Use context manager on connect, then commit/rollback will be done automatically.


Get rid of the single quotes around the %s placeholders.
